# jenetics: Fitness: Assign an object to the determination of fitness & complex fitness result type

Tags: fitness, jenetics

I am using an `IntegerChromosome` which is an encoding for the actual problem. To determine the fitness I have to decode from the `IntegerChromosome`, or more the `IntegerGene` values, to the actual base type for the optimization problem. So, e.g. `IntegerGene` value 0 means an instance of type `Class` with values `A`, 1 means an instance of type `Class` with values `B` and so on. So, 01233210 would translate to ABCDDCBA. Only the latter I can evaluate. I get this information at runtime in a class `FitnessInput`.

Therefore I need to pass `FitnessInput` to the determination of the fitness function. Looking at a simple [example](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/algorithms-genetic/src/main/java/com/baeldung/algorithms/ga/jenetics/SimpleGeneticAlgorithm.java) I found that the determination of the fitness, in the `eval()` method in the example, takes place in a static method. Is there a concept and a related example how to pass runtime objects to the determination of the fitness rather than overwriting a static variable in the class where `fitness()` is implemented?

---

A second question related to the problem of fitness determination. I found examples where simple data types `Integer`, `Double` are used for the determination of the fitness. While this is of course reasonable, I would like to return an object to the user for the best phenotype, which contains all intermediate results for the determination of its fitness. I guess this should be possible if my return object implements `Comparable`. How can I make use, e.g., of the `Function` interface for that?

Answer (score 1):

You might have a look at the [Codec](https://jenetics.io/javadoc/jenetics/6.1/io/jenetics/engine/Codec.html) interface. This interface is responsible for converting the objects of your problem domain into a `Genotype`. If I understand your problem correctly, a possible encoding might look like this:

```
static final List<String> OBJECTS = List.of("A", "B", "C", "D");
static final int LENGTH = 10;

static final Codec<List<String>, IntegerGene> CODEC = Codec.of(
    // Create the Genotype the GA is working with.
    Genotype.of(IntegerChromosome.of(0, OBJECTS.size() - 1, LENGTH)),
    // Convert the Genotype back to your problem domain.
    gt -> gt.chromosome().stream()
        .map(IntegerGene::allele)
        .map(OBJECTS::get)
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
);

// Calculate the fitness function in terms of your problem domain.
static double fitness(final List<String> objects) {
    return 0;
}

static final Engine<IntegerGene, Double> ENGINE = Engine
    .builder(Main::fitness, CODEC)
    .build();
```

The `Codec` creates a `Genotype` which consists of an `IntegerChromosome` of length 10 and converts it back to your problem domain.

I'm not sure if I understood your second question correctly. But if you want to collect the intermediate results as well, you can use the `Stream::peek` method.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final List<Phenotype<IntegerGene, Double>> intermediateResults = new ArrayList<>();
    
    final var bestPhenotype = ENGINE.stream()
        .limit(Limits.bySteadyFitness(25))
        .peek(er -> intermediateResults.add(er.bestPhenotype()))
        .collect(EvolutionResult.toBestPhenotype());
}
```

Comment: I'll have a look at the `Codec` interface. For the second question: In your example the `Engine<IntegerGene,Double>` is used. Thus, the fitness is determined by a `Double` if I understand correctly. What do I have to implement for the determination of the fitness for `MyFitnessResultType`, if I want to use `Engine<IntegerGene,MyFitnessResultType>`? From what I see, the type has to implement `Comparable` and `Function`?

Comment: Your `MyFitnessResultType` only have to implement the `Comparable` interface. In my example, the signature of the fitness function will then look like this: `static MyFitnessResultType fitness(List<String> objects);` You don't need to implement the `Function` interface.

Comment: But then I could not use the `Engine` builder using the genotype factory?!

Comment: No, but you don't have to. You build the `Engine` either with a `Codec` or a `Factory<Genotype>` (or a `Problem` object). The `Codec` combines your `Genotype` factory with the _encoding_ to your problem domain. It might be that you are no longer able to use all `Selector` or `Alterer` implementations, which can require that the fitness value is numeric. And you are only promising to be comparable.